# add new postal address to existing contact

Tags: android, xamarin.android, addressbook

I try to add an address on an existing contact:

```
// insert

operations.Add(ContentProviderOperation.NewInsert(ContactsContract.Data.ContentUri)
                                       .WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.ContactId, contact.Id)
                                       .WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.RawContactId, GetRawContactId(contact.Id))
                                       .WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.Mimetype, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.ContentItemType)
                                       .WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Pobox, address.PoBox)
                                       .WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Street, address.Street)
                                       .WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.City, address.City)
                                       .WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Postcode, address.Postcode)
                                       .WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.Country, address.Country)
                                       .WithValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.CommonColumns.Type, GetAddressContactInfoType(address.InfoType))
                                       .Build());
```

but all I get is a

```
Android.Content.OperationApplicationException: insert failed
```

any suggestions?

thank you very much in advance

Comment: full stack trace: http://pastebin.com/695PKf3V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found the solution. I had to remove the following line:

```
.WithValue(ContactsContract.Data.InterfaceConsts.ContactId, contact.Id)
```